# Beer shop in Brittany (cave à bières bretonnes située en Bretagne)

Tags: recommendations, craft-beers, buying, brittany, france

I am searching for some shops with large (100+) selection of beers from Brittany.

I have two somewhat different targets:

(1) a shop located in Rennes, more than V&B, or around RN 164, see below:

[image]

(2) an online shop that ships out of France

Any suggestion?

Comment: The title puzzled me... Are the beers supposed to be from Brittany ( "caves à bieres bretonnes") or the shops located in Brittany ("caves situées en Bretagne")?

Comment: Both. The beers are supposed to be from Brittany, and the shops located in Brittany (see image) or online.

Answer (score 3):

Please allow me to recommend the [Cave à bières à Rennes : Chez Alain](https://www.caveabiere-rennes.com/).

The French are more into drinking wine, but this shop does beer a lot of justice.

They have around 350 varieties of beer, both imported and domestic.

It also has a small bar situated on site. What more do you need?

> Cave à bières à Rennes : Chez Alain
>
> Une large gamme de bières artisanales du monde entier en Ille-et-Vilaine
>
> Découvrez une diversité de bières 100% artisanales à base de malt minutieusement sélectionné. Des bières bretonnes, belges, européenne, ou du reste du monde, sélectionnez votre bière préférée.
>
> Poussez les portes de notre cave à bières à Rennes et découvrez nos nouveautés et nos derniers arrivages. Vous trouverez 350 références de bières françaises et étrangères (Belgique, Etats-Unis, Canada, Écosse, Norvège, Suède, Italie, Danemark, Hollande, Angleterre, Suisse, Allemagne, République Tchèque…).

Having been there some years ago, it is awesome.

**Caveat:**

On-line shops may only do sales on-line and may or may not have an inventory shop to browse in. Some are simply *middle men* so to speak.

Comment: "The French are more into drinking wine" - I'd say the French are more known for producing wine... since I have moved here, I've noticed at least as much beer consumed as wine. But, it's true that they consume a lot of both!  ;)

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to Ken Graham.

After returning from Brittany, I can say that Chez Alain was a good choice, but a little too international.

I discovered [Le marchand de biere](https://www.marchand-biere.bzh) in Rennes, not too far from Chez Alain, which I preferred for a larger choice of only local beers.